# Finding euclidean difference between coordinates in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, euclidean-distance

I am trying to calculate the difference between coordinates using numpy using following code :

```
X = np.random.random((1000, 3))
# using broadcasting to calculate to find pairwise diffrence
diff = X.reshape(1000, 1, 3) - X
D = (diff**2).sum(2)
```

Can somebody explain me what the above two lines are doing? I don't understand how this calculates the euclidean distance for the coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one calculates a random *1000×3* matrix, all values are between 0 and 1, so the rows represent points in a 3D unit cube:

```
np.random.random((1000, 3))
```

Next we use reshape, to construct an *1000×1×3* matrix, with `X.reshape(1000, 1, 3)`.

Now when we subtract that reshaped matrix something happens that is very popular in numpy: broadcasting. So we have a *1000×1×3* matrix, and a *1000×1×3* matrix. That means that we will "*blow up*" the first matrix by hypothetically repeating the second dimension 1000 times. So a matrix like:

```
[[[x1, y1, z1]],
 [[x2, y2, z2]],
 ...
 [[xn, yn, zn]]]
```

Will now be transformed into:

```
[[[x1, y1, z1], [x1, y1, z1], ..., [x1, y1, z1]],
 [[x2, y2, z2], [x2, y2, z2], ..., [x2, y2, z2]],
  ...         , ...              , ...          ,
 [[xn, yn, zn], [xn, yn, zn], ..., [xn, yn, zn]]]
```

Where each triple is repeated *n* times per row.

We blow up the second matrix as well, such that:

```
[[x1, y1, z1],
 [x2, y2, z2],
 ...
 [xn, yn, zn]]
```

(mind that we have one pair of square brackets less per row), will blow up to:

```
[[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], ..., [xn, yn, zn],
 [x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], ..., [xn, yn, zn],
 ...         , ...,          ..., ...         ,
 [x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], ..., [xn, yn, zn]]
```

If we now subtract the two matrices, we get:

```
[[[x1-x1, y1-y1, z1-z1], [x1-x2, y1-y2, z1-z2], ..., [x1-xn, y1-yn, z1-zn]],
 [[x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1], [x2-x2, y2-y2, z2-z2], ..., [x2-xn, y2-yn, z2-zn]],
  ...         , ...              , ...          ,
 [[xn-x1, yn-y1, zn-z1], [xn-x2, yn-y2, zn-z2], ..., [xn-xn, yn-yn, zn-zn]]]
```

So we constructed a *1000×1000×3* matrix, where the *i,j*-th element is a 3-tuple containing the difference of the coordinates of the point specified at row *i* and the coordinate of the point specified at row *j*. We store that result in `diff`.

Next we use `diff**2` to caculate the elementwise square, so now:

```
(diff**2)[i, j] == array([(xi-xj)**2, (yi-yj)**2, (zi-zj)**2])
```

Finally we call `.sum(2)` on that matrix (this means `axis=2`). This means that we for each element of `(diff**2)` will sum up the components, so then:

```
((diff**2).sum())[i, j] == (xi-xj)**2 + (yi-yj)**2 + (zi-zj)**2
```

So we calculate a *1000×1000* matrix where the `[i, j]`-th element is the *square* of the *Euclidean* distance. Note that we do *not* calculate the *Euclidean* distance, but its square. We can however calculate it, by applying `np.sqrt(..)` on the result, so:

```
D = np.sqrt((diff**2).sum(2))  # Euclidean distance
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a very detailed answer.